# Can I sell apps or not?

Tags: android, google-play

Ok this got me really angry. If I search the supported countries list,my country(Romania),isn't there. However I tried to make a dev account on the market...Guess what! everything works,and now I got at the stage where I must pay the 25$ fee.

How is this possible? I can't find my country on the supported countries list,but I got at the paying page,and my country is at those adresses.

Can someone tell me if I can or not to sell apps if I'm from Romania?! I mailed google but nothing...

Comment: no you can't http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=150324 you can only publish free apps(and yes you have to pay fee for publishing)

Comment: You cannot sell app if Google haven't activated it in your country. However, every developer must pay a 25$ fee.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [Android Market Help page](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=150324), you cannot sell apps from Romania (yet). You can, however, distribute free apps (according to [this page](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=138294)).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can't I'm afraid.

Refer [this list](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=138294) which mentions providing you are in [these](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=150324) supported countries (Romania isn't) you can sell.

I also can't specify a price to Romania specifically from my Android market, which would imply the same results - you cannot.

Attached image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think Google are in the process of rolling out Merchant accounts in more countries, but at this moment in time you can't!

I'd try to get in touch with someone from a country in which you can, a friend or find a business partner and work out some sort of deal.